# Verbs corresponding to 'showed' for other senses

Tags: word-request

Consider the sentence:

> The teacher **showed** the students what an elephant looks like.

(This sentence is perhaps more naturally written as 'The teacher showed the students an elephant.' but I need to phrase it this way to explain my question.)

What would be the corresponding verbs for other senses? For instance,

> The teacher   ***_*__*_*__**   the students what a rose smells like.
>   The teacher   ***_*__*_*__**   the students what a fire alarm sounds like.
>   The teacher   ***_*__*_*__**   the students what a mango tastes like.

Comment: I consider "showed" to be general enough to work for all of them, actually, and—in this exact phrasing—that might be the best you can do.

Comment: *Show* has not been restricted to what is visible for at least 800 years; it very early acquired the sense of 'make perceptible or intelligible'.

Comment: [_Describe_](http://acreativemoment.com/2008/07/18/words-to-describe-smell-sound-taste-touch/) is also a good word. However you _describe something to someone_ or describe how/why/what etc.

Answer (score 2):

> The teacher   ______   the students what a rose smells like.
>   The teacher   ______   the students what a fire alarm sounds like.
>   The teacher   ______   the students what a mango tastes like.

The answer, as stated in the comments, is simply *showed*.

Consider the second sense of *show* in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/show) (my emphasis):

> *(transitive)* to present to view; **exhibit**

Essentially, you are putting on display some characteristic of an item. While you can be more specific, this would be the idiomatic way of expressing this. *One* other possibility is *highlight*, but that is more natural if you are contrasting a property of an object with another.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both the comments. *[Show](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SHOW)* can serve all the blanks in your sentences; however, I'd like to give some options here since there are two events where *senses* are involved. I cannot *show* you the sense I feel!

**Note that I take this statement of yours -** *This sentence is perhaps more naturally written as 'The teacher showed the students an elephant.'* So, I **consider that you actually want to say** that the *teacher showed the students an elephant.* and not *The teacher showed the students what an elephant looks like.*

It's more technical but correct.

So,

> The teacher gave olfactive demonstration of a rose. 
>   The teacher demonstrated the (sound of) fire alarm to the students. 
>   The teacher gave gustatorial demonstration of a mango.

look better to me.

Comment: Your first and third example sentences sound extremely unusual to me. I find it difficult to imagine someone saying those sentences seriously.

Comment: @ogicu8abruok yes they are bit technical but correct